# console.log not showing in my firebug

Tags: firefox, logging, console, firebug, jsfiddle

In [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/T9AYR/), I have this simple code:

```
console.log('yep');
alert('hello');
```

I can see the alert window but nothing in my `firebug` console.

Is there a reason why ?

[image]

Comment: This issue is back in Firebug 2.0.18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in [Firebug 1.11.0a5](https://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.11/firebug-1.11.0a5.xpi). More info is [here](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5954)

Comment: I'm running 1.11.2 and it also does not work in that version.

Answer (score 7):

I'm encountering it as well on my FF15.
In my case, it is caused by the built-in "web console" in "web developer"
Ctrl+Shift+K

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

> Beginning with Firefox 4, the old Error Console has been deprecated in favor of the new, improved Web Console. The Web Console is something of a heads-up display for the web, letting you view error messages and other logged information. In addition, there are methods you can call to output information to the console, making it a useful debugging aid, and you can evaluate JavaScript on the fly.

Comment: It's not right in my case. Finally I get that the console.log() is disabled by some setting. I wrote a simple html to test it ( my FF both have Firebug & Web Developer ), and it works well, and can print out the log. But I've no idea how to disable console.log() yet.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to using console.log (I used to use alert()s) and was wondering why I couldn't see console.log messages in Firebug too.

After a several minutes of web searching I realised the console mode was set to 'Debug Info'. Clicking the 'All' button made all my messages appear.

The OP didn't make this particular mistake, admittedly. It's a rookie error, but still non-obvious enough (I haven't used Firebug for a while) to bring me here before I managed to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue with firefox 29 Beta (and Australis) Just restart the browser :)
EDIT : seems like its it's not true : on the first page load, it display the log, on the others not (need to open the page in a new tab). Apparently it's queryLoader2 jQuery plugin